# is undefined to $("inputElement").val()

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax

I have this code in Masterpage of an asp.net project

```
<div style="display:none">
       <input id="txtPageIDMaster" name="txtPageIDMaster" type="text" value="0" runat="server"/>
    <input id="txtOnLineUserMaster" type="text" value="0" runat="server"/>
    </div>
```

and in script tag :

```
alert($("#txtPageIDMaster").val())
```

but give me this alert : undefined

Comment: Don't tag asp.net web forms controls with MVC

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
alert($("<%= txtPageIDMaster.ClientID %>").val())
```

Why? Because asp.net sets its own id for controls. So the [ClientID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) property gives you the generated ID.

As of ASP.NET 4 this is based now on the [ClientIDMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientidmode.aspx) property. Which can be four values :

- `ClientIDMode.Inherit`
- `ClientIDMode.AutoID` (Which is default and how it always was pre .NET4)
- `ClientIDMode.Preditable`
- `ClientIDMode.Static` (this is when the html ID is set to the asp.net ID property)

---

Asp.net MVC doesn't do this. You're in full control of your html and your ID's are never auto generated.

Comment: thank you for your great description but this line of code dose not work in my context;

Comment: @user1129318 `(1)` Are you using asp.net -> web forms or **asp.net-mvc **, `(2)` When the page is rendered, in Chrome maybe, can you inspect your element to see what its ID is `(3)` Can you also check your browser console for any other errors?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
alert(document.getElementById('txtPageIDMaster').value);
```

Comment: I have tested this line early but i get undefined.

Comment: please try one more time because it will work in any platform

Answer (score 0):

From the jQuery perspective:

1. Is jQuery installed on the page?
2. Is the alert(...) statement inside an appropriate structure, eg.

javascript:

```
$(function(){
    alert($("#txtPageIDMaster").val());//adapted for ASP.net as per gideon's suggestion, I expect
};)
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have mentioned runat=server the control will be considered as server side control so at time of finding it in javascript you need to specify controlname.clientID so you need to mention in javascript as follow

```
alert(document.getElementById('<%= txtPageIDMaster.ClientID %>').value);
```